# Extending Query<T, ..> to more than 7 types

Tags: c#, sql, generics, mapping, dapper

I am using Dapper to fetch a list of results. I have a lot of "value"-tables that only contains ID and a name.

I have this SQL;

```
SELECT 
    MedicationScheduleItem.*,
    MedicationSchedule.*,
    Patient.*,
    Medication.*,
    MedicationBrand.*,
    MedicationScheduleItemRepeat.*,
    MedicationType.*,
    Measure.*

FROM MedicationScheduleItem
JOIN MedicationSchedule ON (MedicationSchedule.Id = MedicationScheduleItem.MedicationScheduleId)
JOIN Patient ON (Patient.Id = MedicationSchedule.PatientId)
JOIN Medication ON (Medication.Id = MedicationScheduleItem.MedicationId)
JOIN MedicationBrand ON (MedicationBrand.Id = Medication.MedicationBrandId)
JOIN MedicationType ON (MedicationType.Id = Medication.MedicationTypeId)
JOIN Measure ON (Measure.Id = Medication.MeasureId)
LEFT JOIN MedicationScheduleItemRepeat ON (MedicationScheduleItemRepeat.MedicationScheduleItemId = MedicationScheduleItem.Id)
```

and I am trying to map that SQL to a model like this;

```
using Dapper;

//... 

private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

//... 

private IEnumerable<MedicationScheduleResultModel> QueryMedicationScheduleResultModels(string sql, object parameters = null)
{
    var results = new Dictionary<int, MedicationScheduleResultModel>();

    _connection.Query<MedicationScheduleItem, MedicationSchedule, Patient, Medication, MedicationBrand, MedicationScheduleItemRepeat, MedicationType, Measure, MedicationScheduleResultModel>(sql,
                (medicationScheduleItem, medicationSchedule, patient, medication, medicationBrand, medicationScheduleItemRepeat, medicationType, measure) =>
                {
                    MedicationScheduleResultModel viewModel;
                    if (!results.TryGetValue(medicationSchedule.Id, out viewModel))
                    {
                        results.Add(medicationSchedule.Id, new MedicationScheduleResultModel
                        {
                            Id = medicationSchedule.Id,
                            Patient = patient,
                            TimeCreated = medicationSchedule.TimeCreated,
                            StartDate = medicationSchedule.StartDate,
                            Schedules = new List<MedicationScheduleItemResultModel>()
                            {
                                BuildMedicationScheduleItemResultModel(medicationScheduleItem,
                                    medicationScheduleItemRepeat, medication, medicationBrand, medicationType, measure)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        viewModel.Schedules.Add(BuildMedicationScheduleItemResultModel(medicationScheduleItem,
                            medicationScheduleItemRepeat, medication, medicationBrand));
                    }

                    return viewModel;
                }, parameters, splitOn: "Id, MedicationScheduleItemId");

    return results.Values;
}

private static MedicationScheduleItemResultModel BuildMedicationScheduleItemResultModel(MedicationScheduleItem medicationScheduleItem, MedicationScheduleItemRepeat medicationScheduleItemRepeat, Medication medication, MedicationBrand medicationBrand, MedicationType medicationType, Measure measure)
{
    return new MedicationScheduleItemResultModel()
    {
        Id = medicationScheduleItem.Id,
        ExecuteTime = medicationScheduleItem.ExecuteTime,
        RepeatTimeSpan = medicationScheduleItemRepeat != null
            ? (TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.FromTicks(medicationScheduleItemRepeat.RepeatTimeSpan)
            : null,
        Medication = new MedicationResultModel()
        {
            Id = medication.Id,
            Name = medication.Name,
            Brand = new MedicationBrand()
            {
                Id = medicationBrand.Id,
                Name = medicationBrand.Name
            },
            Measure = measure.Name,
            Type = medicationType.Name,
            Weight = medication.Weight
        }
    };
}
```

But the `_connection.Query<T, ..>` fails because there is to many generics types.

Is there a way to get this to work, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What is `_connection`?

Comment: I have updated the question, it is a `IDbConnection`

Comment: can you post the code for `BuildMedicationScheduleItemResultModel`?  if all you're doing in there is constructing a `MedicationScheduleItemResultModel` and assigning properties from the input objects, then you should modify your SQL query to return the appropriate columns and have Dapper directly create the `MedicationScheduleItemResultModel` for you.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I have updated the question, all I am doing is mapping the fields to a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mapping your SQL result to all those types only to use them in initializing another type, you could try to map directly to the eventual type you are interested in.

So instead of this:

```
_connection.Query<MedicationScheduleItem, MedicationSchedule, Patient, 
    Medication, MedicationBrand, MedicationScheduleItemRepeat, MedicationType,
    Measure, MedicationScheduleResultModel>(...
```

this might be sufficient to build the object graph you need:

```
_connection.Query<MedicationScheduleResultModel, Patient, 
    MedicationScheduleItemResultModel, MedicationResultModel, MedicationBrand>(...
```

Of course, this would require modifying your `SELECT` in order to return the appropriate fields. Something like...

```
SELECT
    -- columns that directly map to MedicationScheduleResultModel properties
    MedicationSchedule.id,
    MedicationSchedule.time_created TimeCreated, 
    MedicationSchedule.start_date StartDate,

    -- columns that directly map to Patient properties
    -- (to be used as MedicationScheduleResultModel.Patient)
    Patient.id, 
    Patient.name,

    -- columns that directly map to MedicationScheduleItemResultModel properties
    MedicationScheduleItem.id,
    MedicationScheduleItem.execute_time ExecuteTime,
    MedicationScheduleItemRepeat.repeat_time RepeatTime,

    -- columns that directly map to MedicationResultModel properties
    Medication.id,
    Medication.name,
    Measure.name,
    MedicationType.name,
    Medication.weight,

    -- columns that directly map to MedicationBrand properties
    MedicationBrand.id, 
    MedicationBrand.name
...
```

Hope you get the idea.

You might even go further and flatten, for example, the `MedicationResultModel` so that instead of containing a complex `MedicationBrand` property, it contains `MedicationBrandId` and `MedicationBrandName` properties. But that depends on whether this is appropriate for the rest of your design or not.

Comment: Okay, so dapper will known the order and then map correctly? And should I alias MedicationType.Name to Type? Otherwise I will have 2 with the name 'Name'

Comment: @TryingToImprove yes, dapper will know when a new type starts when it sees a new column named "id". If you wanted to start at a different column name, you'd need to explicitly state that column using the `SplitOn` parameter of the `Query` method. And no, two columns named `Name` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @TryingToImprove actually, looking at the dapper code again, your column names need to match property names (although it may be case-insensitive). So it will succesfully map `id` column to `Id`, but in case of `start_date` it won't map to `StartDate` so you need to provide a column alias (I've edited my example above).

Comment: Thank you it works, - My DB coloumn have the same names as the C# objects, så could do this: http://pastebin.com/kipYdqiy